# Make part of text box read only in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to create a text box with a predefined value if the user clicks a radio button. The user should be able to append to the value, but not modify it. I have the following:

```
handleRadio: function (that) {
    var communicationName = $('#communicationName');
    communicationName.show().next('p').remove();
    if ($('#request_for_information').is(':checked')) {
        var radioVal = that.val();
        communicationName.val(radioVal);
        var readOnlyLength = $('#communicationName').val().length;
        $('#communicationName').on('keypress keydown', function (event) {
            if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39) && (event.which != 35) && (event.which != 36))
            && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength)
            || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        communicationName.val('').prop('readonly', false);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working in IE8, which is the company standard.  Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Even if the above code did work, is there anything in there that stops me typing in the middle of the "read only" value?  I think you'd be better off representing the read only value a different way.

Comment: The keypress/keydown function only allows you to hit left, right, end or home. That function only applies within the read only value.

Comment: Sorry, yeah.  I see that now.  I still think it's not the best way to do what you want.  People are used to certain things behaving in certain ways, and you're making it do something totally different.  For example, instead of radios and a textbox, why not have a select next to the textbox, so you don't need to prefix the text - the value would be right there next to it and you wouldn't be able to edit that.

Comment: It's more of a business requirement. However if no workaround exists, I'll probably add a label to show/hide

Comment: That's a shame.  It can be a real pain when you "have" to do something that's just plain wrong.  Such is the life of a programmer :)